# How to get elements when class name is unknown?

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

I have an HTML document in which there is a table that contains rows that might or might not have a class, for example:

```
<tr class="">
  <th>Name</th>
  <td class="row-text">Myname</td>
</tr>
```

In the above example, the row doesn't have a class. However I need to get the column value (ie. `MyName`). The only unique value in such rows the is the header tag.

Is there a way to get the correct row by header value using XPath?

Comment: Can XPath utilize CSS selectors like JQuery in JavaScript does?

Comment: @Matt Yes, something like `"//*[contains(@class,'my_css_class')]"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do it with the [`following-sibling` axis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/following-sibling):

```
//th[. = 'Name']/following-sibling::td
```

Or, through the `tr` parent element:

```
//tr[th = 'Name']/td
```

Answer (score 1):

@alecxe answer is right. I would add other similar alternatives:

This one looks for all the `tr` with a `th`  that contain `'Name'` as a **substring** (if there are more than one element with the text 'Name' as part of their content they will be selected too); and chooses the `td` inside the `tr`

```
//tr[contains(th, 'Name')]/td
```

This other is similar, but only gives you the elements with the **exact match**, and also takes care of **normalizing** the whitespaces, which is useful as sometimes exact matches are not found because there might be whitespaces or newlines before the text that prevent the exact match. It finds the `th` moves to the parent (`..`) and finally to the `td`

```
//th[normalize-space(text()) = 'Name']/../td
```

Remember that you can use the `$x("some/xpath")` function in the Chrome and Firefox consoles to check for xpaths; similar to the `$("some css")` for CSS selectors.